# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 How can I change information of User created page?

Tags: ios, facebook-page, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing one iOS application in wich I integrate FaceBook via Facebook iOS SDK 3.1. I want to change User created page information eg. Cover Photo, Profile Picture , Description, About etc. programmatically. I found some urls on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ but I dont't know How to use those urls with parameters.Any example is there for this type of functionality?